# Visual studio fails to uninstall an Apache Cordova plugin

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, apache-cordova

i used the visual studio's built in plugin installer in config.xml to install a plugin called "pushbots", but i didn't no longer need it so i tried to remove it.
It says "Error during install" and the build fails with 167 errors.
[image]

from installation log:

```
Error: Uh oh!
ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:\[project folder]\platforms\android\pushbots-cordova-plugin'
```

build errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;  OIU     1   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       D:\
[project]\platforms\android\src\com\pushbots\plugin\PushbotsPlugin.java:4: 
error: package com.pushbots.push does not exist OIU     1
```

I don't need to get the plugin working, i just need to get rid of the build errors. This is my first apache cordova app and i have no idea what to do.

Comment: You tried by command line too?

Comment: Have you tried it on a new blank empty Cordova app?

Answer (score 0):

used an application cordova-check-plugins, it allows to delete all plugins.
source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932758/removing-cordova-plugins-from-the-project)